# Colspan in export from classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

In a file, i have the headers for export file to a MS EXCEL

```
Session.CodePage=65001
response.charset="utf-8" 
Server.ScriptTimeout = 9999999
response.write "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"">  "
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment;filename=websad_ExcelPlan.xls"
Response.Buffer = true
```

And i created a HTML table:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But the attribute `colspan`is ignored. how to use the `colspan` in export?

Comment: Works for me. Are you creating the table through asp code? If so, please add that too.

Comment: The table is created in same asp code, closing tags `<%%>` for the headers and after follow the html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the double qoutes in colspan value.. it should be like this colspan=8

Comment: That would make the html invalid, wouldn't it?